# What's the best place for external libraries in a PHP project?

Tags: php

What's the best practice for locating external libraries in a PHP project (e.g., GoogleMapAPI, Recaptcha, etc.)? Right now I have all classes in /lib or subdirectories thereof, and am using Zend convention for naming (e.g., class Foo sits in /lib/Foo.php, class Db_Bar sits in /lib/Db/Bar.php).

But should I segregate third-party stuff? If so, how? Where? Inside /lib? Elsewhere? Note: Autoloading of these classes is not an issue because they are always included/required explicitly where needed (unlike my own classes).

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, putting everything in `/lib`. I'd suggest separating each one into its own subfolder, since many libraries will have multiple files. So have `/lib/googlemaps`, `/lib/recaptcha` and so on.

If you're still not sure, perhaps take a look at some frameworks like CodeIgniter. Joomla uses the system I described above. They even have `/lib/joomla` for the whole Joomla framework.

There's no need to over-think it. As long as it's easy to find and include the libraries, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually the structure I follow for organizing my apps:

```
myproject/
myproject/app
myproject/app/controllers
myproject/app/views
myproject/app/models
myproject/config
myproject/log
myproject/lib
myproject/lib/external
myproject/lib/external/Zend -> symlinked to -> /whatever/libraries/zend-1.x.x/
myproject/lib/external/GoogleMaps/ -> symlinked to -> /whatever/libraries/gmaps-1.x/
myproject/lib/core (to my application)
myproject/lib/core/Adapters/Rest.inc
myproject/lib/core/Facades/SimpleTwitterApi.inc
....etc....
```

It's helpful to have the lib/external because I usually symlink different versions of libraries (Zend, etc.) and updating them becomes more manageable. Also, if you use a version control system, it's interesting to see how many commits are in lib/core vs. lib/external. Additionally, you can use something like phploc to see if the bulk of your code is in the external libraries or in your core.

Btw, it's good to hear that autoloading isn't an issue and you're explicitly including/requiring files as needed :)

Comment: This is very close to what I do. I normally include a specific version of the libraries I'm using rather than linking to them to avoid version mismatches, but of course there are other ways to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't be aligned with Linux best-practices e.g. /usr/share with a lib hierarchy per module type ?

Answer (score 0):

You could always keep the names and locations of the files in a database if you don't want to store them on your server. Then you can load them as you need them by using the stored information. Also this would prevent you from having to change many webpages when there is a change that needs to be made.

Comment: ... or have a "clever" auto-loader i.e. config file for an auto-loading class.